# Issue with sending OTP SMS with Twilio in React.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twilio

Hey I am trying to create a form which verify users phone number before submitting I am getting the issue in console with the send and verify api part in console the error showing are

```
RegistrationForm.js:21     POST http://localhost:3000/api/sendOTP 404 (Not Found)

RegistrationForm.js:21     POST http://localhost:3000/api/verifyOTP 404 (Not Found)
```

My files for backed and fronted are something like this

```html
my-app/
├── backend/
│   ├── server.js
│   └── ...
├── src/
│   ├── RegistrationForm.js
│   └── ...
├── ...
```

Here is the code for
RegistrationForm.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const [restaurantName, setRestaurantName] = useState('');
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
  const [otpSent, setOtpSent] = useState(false);

  const handlePhoneNumberChange = (event) => {
    setPhoneNumber(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleOtpChange = (event) => {
    setOtp(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSendOTP = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('/api/sendOTP', {  // Update the URL
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          phoneNumber,
        }),
      });
  
      setOtpSent(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // Handle error and show error message to the user
    }
  };
  

const handleVerifyClick = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('./api/verifyOTP', {  // Update the URL
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        phoneNumber,
        otp,
      }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.success) {
      setIsVerified(true);
    } else {
      alert('OTP verification failed. Please try again.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    // Handle error and show error message to the user
  }
};


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // Make an API call to your backend to save registration data
    try {
      await fetch('/api/registerRestaurant', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          restaurantName,
          address,
          phoneNumber,
        }),
      });

      alert('Restaurant registered successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      // Handle error and show error message to the user
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Restaurant Registration</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Restaurant Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={restaurantName}
            onChange={(event) => setRestaurantName(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Address:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={address}
            onChange={(event) => setAddress(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Phone Number:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={phoneNumber}
            onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
            disabled={isVerified}
          />
          {!isVerified && (
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={handleSendOTP}
              disabled={otpSent}
            >
              Send OTP
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
        {otpSent && (
          <div>
            <label>OTP:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={otp}
              onChange={handleOtpChange}
              disabled={isVerified}
            />
            {!isVerified && (
              <button type="button" onClick={handleVerifyClick}>
                Verify OTP
              </button>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
        <div>
          {isVerified && (
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          )}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegistrationForm;
```

And Here is the code for server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const twilio = require('twilio');
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const client = twilio(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post('./api/sendOTP', async (req, res) => {
  const { phoneNumber } = req.body;

  try {
    const verification = await client.verify.services(process.env.TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID)
      .verifications.create({ to: phoneNumber, channel: 'sms' });

    console.log(verification.sid); // Log verification SID for reference

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'OTP sent successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send OTP' });
  }
});

app.post('./api/verifyOTP', async (req, res) => {
  const { phoneNumber, otp } = req.body;

  try {
    const verificationCheck = await client.verify.services(process.env.TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID)
      .verificationChecks.create({ to: phoneNumber, code: otp });

    if (verificationCheck.status === 'approved') {
      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ success: false });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to verify OTP' });
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the routes don't existing. This might be caused by the dot in the route. Can you try

```js
app.post('/api/sendOTP' ...
```

instead of

```js
app.post('./api/sendOTP' ...
```

Comment: hey i tried it too its still showing :3000/api/sendOTP:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This issue is definitely related to your backend. I'd suggest using Postman or curl (i.e. without the frontend) to test if you registered the paths correctly